# jQuery Success Function to update the Table

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm working with MVC3.
Following is my Controller:

```
     public ActionResult TRUnutilizedOwnership(string strGeo, string strVertical, int ? intMonth, int ? intFlag) {

         if (strVertical == null) {
             strVertical = "All";
         }
         if (strVertical == "All") {
             intFlag = 1;
         } else {
             intFlag = 2;
         }
         if (intMonth == null) {
             intMonth = 5;
         }
         TRUnutilizedOwnershipModel oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel = new TRUnutilizedOwnershipModel();
         TravelReadyCommonEntities objTRCommonEntities = new TravelReadyCommonEntities();
         TRUnutilizedOwnershipEntities objTRUnutilizedOwnershipEntities = new TRUnutilizedOwnershipEntities();
         try {
             oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstGeoEntity = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetGeoVertical(strGeo, intFlag);
             if (strGeo == null) {
                 strGeo = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstGeoEntity[0].Geo;
             }
             oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetUnutilizedOwnership(strGeo, strVertical, intMonth, intFlag);
             oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstGeoEntity = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetGeoVertical(strGeo, intFlag);
             oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstVerticalEntity = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetGeoVerticalChange(strGeo, 2);
             oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.lstMonthEntity = oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel.GetMonth();
             return View(oTRUnutilizedOwnershipModel);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             ILogManager LogManager = new LogManager();
             var frame = new StackFrame(0);
             LogManager.CallLogging(frame, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
             return RedirectToAction("Error", "Common");
         }
     }
```

And I'm using following jQuery,

```
function Dispalymaingrid() {
    var Geo = $('#ddlGeo').val();
    var Vertical = $('#ddlVertical').val();
    var Month = $('#ddlMonth').val();
    if (Vertical == "All") {
        var Flag = 1;
    } else {
        var Flag = 2;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("
        TRUnutilizedOwnership ", "
        TravelReady ")",

        datatype: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            strGeo: Geo,
            strVertical: Vertical,
            intMonth: Month,
            intFlag: Flag
        },
        error: function () {},
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            //return result;
        }
    });
}
```

My view page will show the **defaulttable** when I select some option from *dropdown* and click *submit* button. Table data have to be updated with resulting values.

**What do I have to give in success function of the jQuery (only the Table content should get updated)?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough information but I can tell first you should debug what is the response from your controller:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("
    TRUnutilizedOwnership ", "
    TravelReady ")",

    datatype: "json",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        strGeo: Geo,
        strVertical: Vertical,
        intMonth: Month,
        intFlag: Flag
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        // display error ?
    },
    success: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        // update the table with resp here, e.g: $('.defaulttable').html(resp) ?
    }
});
```

Use the console from Firebug or Chrome dev tools wisely. Hope this helps.